# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: fileupload

Здравствуйте. Понадобилась загрузка файлов на сервер. Да вот беда. Писал на yii и час не мог понять почему в запросе не передается имя файла. Решил сделать простую форму:

```
<html>
<form id="driver-form" method="post" action="/admin/index.php/driver/create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="Driver_image" type="file" name="Driver[image]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

В фаербаге обнаружил в запросе:
    Driver[image]= PNG и далее кракозябры - я так понял содержимое файла.

Что делать? Может в apache запрещена загрузка файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стояла валидация аяксом по сабмиту и файл в аяксе не передавался. Убрал валидацию и все заработало.